# "With all of this knowledge I would be very proud of starting to contribute to improve the health of people."

Tags: sentence-construction

I would like to know how can I express this.

> With all of this knowledge I would be very proud of starting to contribute to improve the health of people.

Comment: proud to start contributing, but this question is really about editing....There is a list of verbs followed by ing forms. Would you **mind** researching that? Would you **stop** doing your homework for tea and biscuits? Would you **begin** playing your instrument now? Would you **finish** saying what you have to say? And so on.

Answer (score 2):

I would change this sentence to this: "With all of this knowledge I would be very proud to start contributing to the improvement of people's health. "

When "begin" is used in non-continuous tenses, you can either use a gerund or an infinitive, so this could be "to start to contribute" or "to start contributing," but I chose the second for style. It can make it easier for the reader to comprehend if you find ways around using the same word, like "to" in this sentence.

Similarly, I changed "to improve the health of the people" to "the improvement of people's health" for style purposes and limit the number of prepositions in this sentence.

Comment: Thank you that you try explaining it. I am confused a bit. I have been taught that the word " proud" attracts the preposition "of".

Comment: Proud is used with "of" when it is followed by a noun but "to" when it is followed by a verb. So you can say "I am proud of my son" or "I am proud to have a son."